# how to build a transition homepage like tumblr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tumblr

I want to build a website similar with [tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com) homepage. On that page, while we click on "30 reason" link, it will load a new pages which as far as I know, it still on the same pages. (if it isn't one the same page, please just correct it.)
First, I want to ask, what technology does tumblr do to achieve that? I mean by using jquery, javascript or ajax? Is there any library already available for us to use?

Second, while transition to the down page, does it load the data one by one, or load all the data at once?

Much appreciate for the answer.
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source?

Comment: @AlexHadley yes, I've already look on the source, but I'm new on programming language, so I don't really understand about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the effect is very easy to achieve using jQuery.

Look into scrollTop() to handle animating the page in a similar way...

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#lower_content').offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
```

... assuming you have an element with an ID of "lower_content" and naturally this depends on the whole layout of your site. It is a bit too much to go over here without at least knowing you have some idea of what you're doing.

As for loading things in - definitely only load what you need. Loading "all data at once" is sort of ambiguous but definitely sounds like a bad idea. Look into jquery's $.ajax() for that one. Again too complex for a total run down of the function. But for a competent programmer that's just getting into jquery, these tips should get you started.

Comment: I think the OP was wondering whether to i) separate each "section" into a different file / page and load them separately (*n* page loads) or ii) make them into one page with 3 `<div>`s, which means 1 page load.

Answer (score 0):

it is done using the margin-top css style. Initially they set margin-top to 0px. On the click of the "30 reasons" the value is set to a negative number. This will be a little jerky. They have smoothed the transition using the new transition css properties (for browsers which are webkit based). As a fallback for older browsers (and IE9), jQuery or similar framework has be used.